# Paypal REST api and configuring direct payment page

Tags: paypal

With the paypal NVP api, we were able to set some options for the generated paypal checkout page using `SetExpressCheckout`. Is there a way to do the following with the new REST api?

- `NOSHIPPING` to tell paypal that I don't need a shipping address.
- `LOCALECODE` to set the gateway in the user's language.
- `HDRIMG` to change the title of the page to a logo.
- `EMAIL` to pre-populate the email in the gateway. *NOTE:* I've tried using `$payerInfo->setEmail()` but apparently this method is only for `credit_card` and not `paypal` requests.
- `SOLUTIONTYPE` to set the billing info by default.
- `LANDINGPAGE` to set the landing page.

I cannot find it in the paypal developer REST api docs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not at this time. We are trying to implement a better mechanism to configure the payment experience than overloading the API calls. Until then please use the classic ExpressCheckout API if these are something that you really need.

Comment: Is there now a _better mechanism_? What do you mean by _overloading the API calls_? More properties in the passed object?

Comment: Same question now after another year, since paypal is pushing to use the REST api, is there now a solution for this with the rest api?