# Setting Landing Page for Direct Pay in Paypal REST API

Tags: rest, paypal

Is there a way to set the landing page for paypal to be to pay with credit card similar to what is possible with the express checkout API?

I am aware of this question - [Paypal REST api and configuring direct payment page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423039/paypal-rest-api-and-configuring-direct-payment-page) but since Paypal refers to stackoverflow to ask questions, I am hoping their developers will see this new question and shed light on the subject, as the issue is over a year old...

Comment: we don't have LANDINGPAGE parameter in REST API yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have `LANDINGPAGE` parameter in REST API yet.

Comment: Thanks, is that in the roadmap?

Comment: yes, it is. It is evolving. Don't have an accurate roadmap, though it should be complete by this year-end.