# Paypal setLandingPageType with REST API

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I found some discussion about this, but I could not find a clear answer. Is there a way to set the landing page to billing when creating a payment operation? Something like:

```
   $payer = new Payer();
   $payer->setLandingPageType("billing");
```

So the user will be redirected to the page to fill in the credit card information directly (i.e., not to the paypal login page)

Comment: We do not have landing page yet in REST API. Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264002/setting-landing-page-for-direct-pay-in-paypal-rest-api

Comment: Is there another way to redirect to that page? maybe using the Web profile api?